# iphone ,how to print the char array

Tags: iphone, arrays, char

I have a char array,char contract[8];and assign the value to array,
and I want to print the value,so I use `NSLog(@"%@",contract);`and build succeeded.but run incorrect.

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithCString:contract encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

Basically, you need to make the C string an NSString object.

Comment: This will make a copy of `contract`. Better use -initWithBytesNoCopy:

Answer (score 3):

If you know the size

```
NSLog(@"%.*s", 8, contract);
```

If contract is a NULL-terminated string

```
NSLog(@"%s", contract);
```

or just convert to NSString

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:contract length:contractLen encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding freeWhenDone:NO] autorelease]);
```

Comment: I copied your code,but get warning"Method'+initWithBytesNoCopy:length:encoding:freeWhenDone:'not found(return type defaults to'id')"

Comment: @Gaojian922188, I've added [NSString alloc] call. The "initWithBytesNoCopy:length:encoding:freeWhen‌ " is an instance method.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1413830-initwithbytesnocopy

Comment: Your first example is for a Pascal string, and it should be `"%.*s"`, you have a typo in your example

Comment: Thanks, @Bert! Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Char *string in myArray) {
    NSLog(@"%@", string);
}
```

Comment: While this might provide an answer to the question, some explanation is required. Please update the question with some explanation of how and why this solution works.

Comment: let myArray = [A,v,S,B,Y,s,E] prints: A v S B Y s E

Answer (score -2):

Please go through [Format Specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html). Try `%c` instead of `%@`. Hope this helps

Comment: %c will only print one char. He is trying to print an array of char.